# Сохранение исходного результата при клике

Tags: javascript

По задумке данный скрипт должен менять цвет блока на красный,
а когда кликаешь на другой блок, то цвет предыдущего блока должен сбрасываться до исходного цвета(зеленый).  Как это реализовать?

```js
document.querySelector('.main').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.className == 'item') {
     e.target.style.background = `${e.target.dataset.color}`;  
  }
})
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item{
  padding: 10px;
  background: #248a52;
  border: 1px solid #006633;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: white;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="item" data-color="red">Блок 1</div>
  <div class="item" data-color="red">Блок 2</div>
  <div class="item" data-color="red">Блок 3</div>
  <div class="item" data-color="red">Блок 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
addEventListener('click', e => {
  const $target = e.target.closest(`.item`);
  if (!$target) return;

  $target.closest(`.main`).querySelectorAll(`.item`).forEach($item => {
    if ($target === $item) {
      $item.style.background = `${e.target.dataset.color}`;
    } else {
      $item.style.removeProperty('background');
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #248a52;
  border: 1px solid #006633;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="item" data-color="red">Первый выбор</div>
  <div class="item" data-color="red">Второй выбор</div>
  <div class="item" data-color="red">Третий выбор</div>
  <div class="item" data-color="red">Четвёрты выбор</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="main">
  <div class="item" data-color="red">Первый выбор</div>
  <div class="item" data-color="red">Второй выбор</div>
  <div class="item" data-color="red">Третий выбор</div>
  <div class="item" data-color="red">Четвёрты выбор</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это новая мода на "глобальный" слушатель?

Comment: А где глобальный слушатель? Разве он плох?

Comment: @OliverPatterson я не знаю исходной вёрстки и поэтому для краткости вешаю глобальный слушатель. Его потом можно перевесить на любой контейнер по вкусу.

Comment: @Хмельни́цький "А где глобальный слушатель?" - в самой первой строчке `js`

Comment: а чем он плох??

Comment: @Хмельни́цький ничем, если вы знаете зачем он вам нужен.

Comment: Вы вызвали forEach это метод массива, а где тут сам массив?  Разве forEach можно использовать без самого массива? Это как?

Comment: @Хмельни́цький вы документацию пробовали читать? Я вызвал метод `forEach` у [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

Comment: Правильно, вы мужик нормальный и руки у вас золотые.

Answer (score 4):

```js
document.querySelector('.main').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.className == 'item') {
    document.querySelectorAll('.main .item').forEach(el => el.style.background = '');
    e.target.style.background = e.target.dataset.color;
  }
});
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #248a52;
  border: 1px solid #006633;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="item" data-color="red">Блок 1</div>
  <div class="item" data-color="red">Блок 2</div>
  <div class="item" data-color="red">Блок 3</div>
  <div class="item" data-color="red">Блок 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ваш код не сработает, если будет два блока `.main`.

Comment: А что значит el ?

Comment: @Хмельни́цький Это зашифрованное слово "element".

Comment: @Igor в данном случае это `event` ибо `event.target`

Comment: @nazarpunk Я лучше знаю, что я зашифровал.

Comment: @Igor блин, перепутал `e` и `el`.

Comment: Вы вызвали forEach это метод массива, а где тут сам массив? Разве forEach можно использовать без самого массива? Это как?

Comment: @Хмельни́цький https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll